# How can I break a string up by spaces in PHP, respecting quoted sub strings?

Tags: php, regex, string, parsing, arguments

How can I break a string up by spaces in PHP, respecting quoted sub strings? I think there must be some command to parse this type of string like arguments but I don't know what that is.

Example string:

```
$string = '12345 abcd "hello world" defgh "nice to meet you" 34554';
```

I normally use one of these three to break up strings. But I don't think they have the capability to break the string up like I'm suggesting.

```
$result = str_replace(' ',"\n",$string);
$result = explode(' ',$string);
$result = preg_replace('#\s#',"\n",$string);
```

Outcome:

```
12345
abcd
"hello
world"
defgh
"nice
to
meet
you"
34554
```

Desired outcome:

```
12345
abcd
hello world
defgh
nice to meet you
34554
```

**UPDATE**

I guess I was impressed with PHP's `parse_str` command to deal with URL query variables and was hoping PHP had something I that could work for this example, sort of like `getopt` does for the command line arguments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [fgetcsv()](http://docs.php.net/fgetcsv) / [str_getcsv()](http://docs.php.net/str_getcsv) for this.

```
<?php
$string = '12345 abcd "hello world" defgh "nice to meet you" 34554';
$row = str_getcsv($string, ' ');
var_dump($row);
```

prints

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "12345"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "abcd"
  [2]=>
  string(11) "hello world"
  [3]=>
  string(5) "defgh"
  [4]=>
  string(16) "nice to meet you"
  [5]=>
  string(5) "34554"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're doing things in the wrong order: first explode on the quotes (so you'll isolate quoted substrings easily), then explode based on the spaces.

I'll let the actual code to you as an exercise, but essentially:

```
12345 abcd "hello world" defgh "nice to meet you" 34554
```

becomes

```
12345 abcd
hello world
defgh
nice to meet you
34554
```

Then you'd break up using spaces, but only the rows that weren't between quotes (that's all those with even indexes, assuming first cell is indexed with 0, which is even):

```
12345 abcd           -> Split
hello world          -> Don't split
defgh                -> Split
nice to meet you     -> Don't split
34554                -> Split
```

so it'd become:

```
12345
abcd
hello world
defgh
nice to meet you
34554
```

Obviously if you can have "escaped quotes", you'll need to consider these somehow - also left as an exercise to the reader (it's easy, really).

Comment: thanks. those commands were not supposed to be sequential - just showing ways i normally parse strings, just to elaborating on the question a little.

Comment: @cwd I know - just giving you some logic that would do the trick (not a PHP expert hence I didn't try and throw some code there). There's more than one way to do it, though, and some might perform better than others (definitely not arguing mine is the best).

Comment: thanks. i did made one more not at the bottom of the question.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
$s = '12345 abcd "hello world" defgh "nice to meet you" 34554';
$m = preg_split('/"([^"]*)"|([^\s]+)/', $s, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
$m = array_values(array_filter(array_map('trim', $m)));
var_export($m);
```

Output is:

```
array (
  0 => '12345',
  1 => 'abcd',
  2 => 'hello world',
  3 => 'defgh',
  4 => 'nice to meet you',
  5 => '34554',
)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work fine:

```
function spaceExplode($var)
{
    $chunks = explode('"', $var);
    array_walk($chunks, function(&$text) {
        $text = trim($text);
    });

    $subchunks = array();
    foreach ($chunks as $key => $value) {
        if ($key % 2 != 0) {
            $subchunks[] = $value;
        } else {
            $subchunks = array_merge($subchunks, explode(' ', $value));
        }
    }

    return $subchunks;
}
```

Another way would be to use `strtok` (suggested by ***@Romain*** in his answer before he edited it :)):

```
function tokenize($var, $char)
{
    $tokens = array(strtok($var, $char));

    do {
        $tokens[] = strtok($char);
    } while(end($tokens) !== false);

    foreach ($tokens as $key => $token) {
        $tokens[$key] = trim($token);

        if (empty($tokens[$key])) {
            unset($tokens[$key]);
        }
    }

    return $tokens;
}
```

Comment: Essentially that's the code that implements what I have suggested as a way to work (hence I upvoted it :D).

Comment: Yeah, I've just read your answer. Didn't know about ```strtok```. I think that solution should be used instead.